# PHP SoapClient constructor very slow

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am new to Web Services.  I am experiencing inexplicably random SoapClient constructor execution times.  Usually the call takes about 10 seconds.  Sometimes it takes less than one second, but this occurrence is less frequent.

[PHP SoapClient Constructor extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506853/php-soapclient-constructor-extremely-slow)

[PHP: SoapClient constructor is very slow (takes 3 minutes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944067/php-soapclient-constructor-is-very-slow-takes-3-minutes)

[Connecting to WCF Web Service is inexplicably slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034479/connecting-to-wcf-web-service-is-inexplicably-slow)

My situation is similar to those in the above threads but the solutions provided in them didn't resolve my issue.

```
// config params
$params = array(
    'trace'        => 1,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'cache_wsdl'   => WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY
);
// this call takes about 10 seconds to remote WSDL
$soap_client = new SoapClient(WSDL_URL,$params);
```

I have played with the different wsdl caching parameters and found WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY to be the fastest.  When using the other caching options, the call takes about 25 seconds on average.

I am not using multiple users.

I have changed the wsdl_cache_dir to a Windows friendly directory in php.ini.

My question is two-fold:

1. Why is the SoapClient constructor seemingly random in how long it takes to execute?  Why does it usually take longer but then sometimes only takes a split second?  Is there a test I can perform to learn why it's behaving this way?
2. Should I be caching/saving the SoapClient object or resource so that when my page visitors move from page to page I don't need to create a new SoapClient and re-parse the WSDL again?  What's the recommended approach to accomplish that?

Any help or nudge in the right direction would be much obliged.  Thank you.

Comment: Is the wsdl file local or remote?

Comment: @datasage I tried both. Local first, then remote. Faster execution times with remote.

Comment: try to create a test client with soapui - http://www.soapui.org/ is it slow as well?

Comment: @jamie0726 Not slow. It took about 2 sec first try and almost instant every subsequent refresh. I gather you're saying its my remote resource, not my end? Why wouldn't my remote resource cache like soapui?

Comment: @ImpudentStrumpet so your "slow" client is on a remote machine and the local soapUI client wasn't? Then it sounds like a network/firewall issue.

Comment: can you shut down the firewall for a test and try it again with your remote client?

Comment: I don't have a remote client. I am running everything from my local machine. The WSDL for my project and WSDL for soapui are remote. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ImpudentStrumpet I'm a little bit confused in following along with this conversation. It sounds like the issue with speed has to do do with loading the a remote wsdl file. Which could be affected by all sorts of network factors.

Comment: Did you try a tcpdump or something like that?

Answer (score 11):

## Check the TTL

TTL defines how long the WSDL lives in cache.

```
 soap.wsdl_cache_ttl integer
```

> Sets the number of seconds (time to live) that cached files will be used instead of the originals.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soap.configuration.php#ini.soap.wsdl-cache-ttl

## Store the WSDL locally

Also you could download the WSDL to the local filesystem and use it as source for `SoapClient`

```
$client = new SoapClient("file://path/wsdl.file", array(
    'location' => "http://domain/ws-endpoint",
));
```